# What is the cheapest way to get from Penn Station New York to Penn Station New Jersey apart from walking/biking?

Tags: budget, buses, new-york-city, new-jersey, nj-transit

I don't mind walking a few minutes to and from each station, for example walking to the 33rd street PATH will allow me to get to Newark for a maximum of $2.75. But what about the bus?

The NJ Transit website is suggesting all sorts of routes for over $5.

Could someone list here all routes that go from vaguely near Penn Station NYC to vaguely near Penn Station NJ, and the costs for each?

Comment: The last sentence is quite rude. I asked the question because as far as I knew/thought, I did not know the answer. You say I already know the answer, but I did not know *that* the answer was already within my knowledge. I also see local bus prices of $1.50, $1.85 and $2 depending on which forum or website or blog I look at. Maybe the prices have gone up on several occasions within the last couple years.

Comment: You did not need to vote it down: if you think I already knew the answer, that's fine, but the answer is still interesting to a lot of people.

Comment: I didn't vote down or up.  I'm sorry my comment seemed rude; I was really just looking for clarification as to why you're asking the question.

Comment: I suppose your comment and the 6 upvotes it got, made my question look like a waste of time, and someone decided to downvote. Having a negative score is something I'm not used to, and I've only seen it on rare occasions when the question is really terrible.

Comment: In this case, I was searching online for over an hour, for a transportation route which is probably one of the most popular in the world, with literally millions of people taking it, so I was shocked that there wasn't one place that just said "This is the cheapest way to get from Penn station to Penn station: [{Answer}]". That's why I thought asking a question here would settle it.

Comment: I think the downvotes came because a request for a list of all routes "vaguely near" one thing to "vaguely near" another is, well, vague. Perhaps if you could demonstrate the research you've attempted in this arena, we'd have a better idea of what you're trying to find— demonstrating initial research effort is, after all, an expectation throughout Stack Exchange. I'm pretty sure NJ Transit and PANYNJ are the only authorities with trans-Hudson routes. Newark is a good distance from Manhattan and in a different state, so $2.75 for the PATH sounds like an amazing bargain to me already.

Comment: @choster: re. the downvotes (plural), at the time I wrote my last comment 13 hours ago, there was 1 downvote and 1 upvote. Now there's been another downvote (from you?) and another upvote. If you think that question was vague, you can comment about it with "-1 for....". Otherwise a downvote is absolutely useless because the asker doesn't know what to improve for next time, and it's even negative-productive because the question gets wasted when people are turned away from answering. Finally, if you actually read the question, you would have seen that I demonstrated initial research effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cheapest option is simple - PATH at $2.75 for the entire trip.

Alternatives are NJ Transit train at $5.25, NJ Transit bus at $6.00, Greyhound starting at about $10, and Amtrak which will be even more.  Of course there's also Taxi, RideShare, etc - all of which will be far more.

Despite being slightly more, the best option is almost certainly to catch a NJ Transit train - they are significantly faster than the other options, do not require a change (as PATH does), and has standard train-style seats.

You excluded walking/bike as options, but even these are more expensive than PATH as you need to cross the Hudson which (unless you choose to take PATH!) requires a ferry trip that will cost more than the PATH fare (or a 25 mile diversion to the George Washington Bridge)

Comment: During my initial research I found someone on TripAdvisor (or somethig similar) answering a similar question by saying that the cheapest way is to walk. Writing this comment made me curious so I explored Google Maps:

Comment: It's possible to walk from Penn to Penn for free, but you'd have to walk North towards Bronx and cross the Hudson river further away than one would hope. The only reasons to do this would be for fun, to see a bit of the city, for the experience, for the sake of walking, etc.

Comment: Further, Googling "biking across hudson river" results in: https://www.dot.ny.gov/regional-offices/region8/other-topics/huds-bridge-crossings, http://www.roberts-1.com/bikehudson/r/r/bridges/index.htm, http://www.outdoorfest.com/community/2014/8/19/cycling-across-the-george-washington-bridge,https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g48283-d12669195-i278972554-Revolution_Rail-North_Creek_New_York.html, http://www.nj.com/news/index.ssf/2013/10/man_plans_commute_to_nyc_--_by_riding_a_bike_on_the_hudson_river.html, https://tinyurl.com/yca75ela, http://walkway.org/

Comment: These were in order of appearance in the Google search, but the best ones are not necessarily listed first. Anyway, the possibility to BIKE over the the river without ferry is far more practical than the possibility to walk over, so while both are perfectly possible, the biking option is significant enough that I need to edit your answer.

Comment: @user121772 The bike option requires a 25 mile diversion in NY/NJ traffic, which means it is not feasible option in any real sense of the word.

Comment: I "chose" your answer. Just be happy with that. Stop reverting the edit.